# List hung processes in Terminal?

Tags: terminal

Is there any way to list only those processes which are hung, i.e., "not responding", in Terminal?

The only way I know to do this is look in Activity Monitor for the ones in red.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following command:

```
ps aux | grep -w Z
```

From `ps` man page:

```
The state is given by a sequence of characters, for example, ``RWNA''.
The first character indicates the run state of the process:

I       Marks a process that is idle (sleeping for longer than about 20 seconds).
R       Marks a runnable process.
S       Marks a process that is sleeping for less than about 20 seconds.
T       Marks a stopped process.
U       Marks a process in uninterruptible wait.
Z       Marks a dead process (a ``zombie'').
```

Comment: works great, I see dozen Google Chrome He.

Comment: Cool, but that returns the processes `grep -w Z` (which I guess is the search itself) and `(Google Drive Ico)` which I don't know what that is?

Comment: @Ze'ev do you use the Google Drive? on line only or have you installed it?

Comment: yes, but why would it list that as zombie? and it's not even the gdrive process

Comment: `ps` isn't going to help any. A process 'not responding' means that it is not going back to WaitNextEvent (which in Cocoa terms means it's not giving it's main NSRunLoop a chance to run). It does not mean the program is idle or asleep or stopped or uninterruptible or dead. Quite the contrary; it usually means the program is very busy, so busy it has stopped paying attention to the outside world. It may be processing a huge amount of work, or it may be in a loop accomplishing nothing, or it may mean it's listening for work on another channel (a mach port, for example).

Comment: Yeah this `ps` thing doesn't accomplish what I want at all. Part of Adobe CC, `aerendercore` freezes up on me several times a day, and needs to be force-quit. It shows in AM as "Not responding". Is there any way to get that info via Terminal?